# Using PostgreSQL CITEXT Extension with jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

The Postgres CITEXT extension helps with cases-insensitive data. This, for example, can be useful when working with emails. See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/citext.html) and [here](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/working-with-email-addresses-in-postgresql). I've defined the following table:

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;

CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  email     CITEXT  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password  TEXT    NOT NULL,
  salt      TEXT    NOT NULL
);
```

and added the following to the `<database>` section in the pom.xml:

```
<forcedType>
  <name>CLOB</name>
  <expression>public.user.email</expression>
  <types>CITEXT</types>
  </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

When I run the code generator, the fields do get generated, but there are a lot of "missing name" warnings in the log output. For example:

```
[INFO] Generating routine       : CitextLt.java
[WARNING] Missing name          : Object citext_ne holds a column without a name at position 1
```

Am I on the right track on integrating the CITEXT extesion with jOOQ?

If so, how do I provide these missing names?

Comment: What jOOQ version are you using?

Comment: I'm using jOOQ 3.8.2, with Maven 3.3.1, and Java 1.8.0_05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in this question:

#### Logging

The `WARN` level is perhaps a bit excessive. I've registered an issue to revert that to `INFO`: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5385

You don't have to worry about those warnings. PostgreSQL supports declaring stored procedures whose parameters are unnamed and can be referenced only by parameter index / position. jOOQ's code generator only indicates that this is "unusual" and that a synthetic parameter name is generated.

This should not affect your using CITEXT with jOOQ.

#### Your forced type configuration

There is currently a bug that prevents you from matching user-defined types with `<types/>`: http://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5363

Just remove your `<types/>` element, and it will work.

Comment: Thanks! There still is a problem though: the <types>CITEXT</types> does not seem to match. It generates a field of type 'Object' instead of 'String'. It works when I only use the <expression> with the fully qualified column name. Can you spot my mistake?

Comment: That's correct. There are two things: 1) The pattern is case-sensitive, so lower-case `citext` would probably be better. 2) There is currently a bug that prevents you from matching user-defined types with `<types/>`: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5363. I'll add this to my answer